# create map[string]struct{} and assign a value

Tags: go

I'm using the github.com/samalba/dockerclient and want to create a Container.
So, the method is CreateContainer, which needs a ContainerConfig.

The ContainerConfig is a struct. And there's a field Volumes, the type of which is type map[string] struct{}.

I know that I could create such a map with `make(map[string]struct{})`

But how do I assign values to the map?

Comment: Read up on [map composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). E.g. `cc := dockerclient.ContainerConfig{Volumes: map[string]struct{}{ "key1": struct{}{}, "key2": struct{}{} } }`. E.g.: https://play.golang.org/p/-ldjIDxVzN. You could also use `empty := struct{}{}` to make it more readable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
cc := &dockerclient.ContainerConfig{
    // ...
    Volumes: map[string]struct{}{
        "foo": struct{}{},
        "bar": struct{}{},
        // ...
    },
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you know for the docker client how to use not empty struct `struct{}{}` but with actual values? I need an equivalent of `-v /host/directory:/container/directory` command line option... let's say I want to mount /mnt/foo directory from host to /mnt/foo on container... How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`Volumes: map[string]struct{}{
"dir1": struct{}{},
"dir2": struct{}{},
},`

Maps only the folder from localhost to docker container. No contents will be mapped.

Comment: Hey, do you know hot to actually map content with it?.. How to put anything instead of just `struct{}{}`? To map dir1 to dir1 on host for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Go 1.19, syntax can be simplified by removing redundant `struct{}`:

```
cc := &dockerclient.ContainerConfig{
    // ...
    Volumes: map[string]struct{}{
        "foo": {},
        "bar": {},
        // ...
    },
}
```